# bash remove/change values from one field with a loop

Tags: bash

I have a file where the 10th column in excel contains prices.

```
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"5000",19.50,justin,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"75,000",19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"100,000",19.50,selena,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"5500",19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"50,000",19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"350,000",19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"50000",19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
```

When it goes to csv the quotes and the comma's stay.
I need to pick out the column that is surrounded by quotes  - I use grep -o
and then after clearing the commas, i get rid of the quotes.

I can't use quotes or comma to delimit in awk because the prices get broken up into different fields.

```
 cat /tmp/wowmom | awk -F ',' '{print $10}'
"5000"
"75
"100
"5500"
"50
"350
"50000"



 while read line
     do
     clean_price=$(grep -o '".*"' $line)
     echo "$clean_price" | tr -d',' > cleanprice1
     echo "cleanprice1" | tr -d'"' > clearnprice2
 done </tmp/wowmom
```

I get errors though  "No such file or directory" on the grep

```
grep:CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"5000",19.50,justin,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,:No such file or directory
grep:CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"75,000",19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,:No such file or directory
grep:CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"100,000",19.50,selena,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,:No such file or directory
grep:CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"50,000",19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,:No such file or directory
grep:CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,"350,000",19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,:No such file or directory
```

I want to some way, Isolate the value within quotes with a grep -o and take out comma from the number , then use awk to take the quotes out of field 10.
I am doinng this manually right now  It is a suprizingly long job - there are thousands of lines on this.

Answer (score 1):

You an use `FPAT` with gnu-awk for this:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+",|[^,]*' '{gsub(/[",]+/, "", $10)} 1' OFS=, file

CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,5000,19.50,justin,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,75000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,100000,19.50,selena,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,5500,19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,50000,19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,350000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,50000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool here.

```
sed -r 's/^(([^,]+,){9})"([^,]+),?([^,]+)"/\1\3\4/' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

The regular expression captures the first nine fields into the first back reference (and also populates the second with the last of the nine fields), the number before the separator comma in the third, and the rest of the number in the fourth, then the substitution glues them back without the skipped elements.

If you have numbers with more than one thousands separator (i.e. above one million), you will need a slightly more complex script.

In terms of what's wrong with your original script, the second argument to `grep` is the name of the file to grep, not the string to grep.  You can use a here string (in Bash) or pipe the string to `grep`, but again, this is not how you do it properly.

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"' <<<"$line"
```

or

```
printf '%s' "$line" | grep -o '"[^"]*"'
```

Notice also the quotes -- omitting quotes are a common newbie error; you can get away with it for a while, and then it bites you.

Comment: Your `sed`  is better than mine: `sed 's/\(.*\)"\([^,]*\)[,]*\([^,]*\)"\(.*\)/\1\2\3\4/'`.

Answer (score 0):

**A pure Bash solution:**

```
while IFS=\" read -r l n r; do
        printf '%s\n' "$l${n//,/}$r"
done < input_file.txt
```

Comment: is there a pure perl solution ?

Comment: @capser I do not know Perl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for perl:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1, eol=>"\n"});
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $filename;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    $row->[9] =~ s/,//g;
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}

close $fh;
```

demo:

```
$ perl csv.pl file
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,5000,19.50,justin,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,75000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,100000,19.50,selena,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,5500,19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,50000,19.50,gomez,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,350000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
CASPER,N,CUSIP,0000000000,WOWMOM,USD,USD,US,B,50000,19.50,bieber,20160506,0,,N,E,,,,,,
```